# stop ie showing security warning when loading non secure images on secure page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the following JQuery plugin to load an image slider http://www.orionseven.com/imageloader/index.php

However this is on a secure page (https) although the images are from external urls so therefore are not on secure pages.  Is there anyway I can stop IE 7 displaying the security warning? Maybe changing my code or something?

Comment: Is it possible for you to save the files to your local server and access them relatively?

Comment: I dont think there is - you can either ensure that the external images come from an HTTPS connection or you can move them locally to your server and reference them relatively

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could proxy images through localy hosted php script.

https://server/image.php?url=foobar.com/foo.gif

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://".$_GET['url']);
?>
```

some comments about cross-site-scripting vulnerability should follow:)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot disable those warnings.

The reason you're seing them is because the user should be notified that non-secure requests are being made (and potentially compromising the security in the process). Turning them off would be bad for the user.

Comment: ...Expect when the "user" is an actual programmer and knows what they're doing, in which case the "user" should be allowed full control. Why not just start locking down all customization options for everyone right? It's working for APPL.

Comment: I mean seriously, are you really advocating that position? I shouldn't have to figure out a work around for a simple app that I'm coding, purely for myself, just because MS *thinks* something is unsafe when I, the actual CODER, know it IS safe.

Comment: Of course I advocate for this. The browser is making a statement of fact. It's telling you that while you're loading a page that is encrypted, some items on the page are not. This defeats the purpose of encrypting anything at all.

Comment: I understand your position, however I don't believe this is something MS should restrict out-right. In my example, I'm using local JS to try and call an API from an external http domain from a well-known sit. It's absurd for MS to not allow the user to decide whether or not they want this "protection" enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be hosting the images on your local server rather than expecting a third party to host them for you. That way they can all be served as HTTPS from the same site, and problem solved.

If you *must* fetch them from the third party server, you'll only be able to solve this issue if that third party also provides HTTPS on their server. In that case, you'd need to modify the URL used to request the images to change the protocol depending on what protocol the main page is being served with.

If you want to load them remotely and that remote server doesn't provide HTTPS, then you cannot get rid of the message -- it's there intentionally in IE to provide a legitimate security warning. You can't override it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. Since M$ considers every single one of their users to be brain-dead and decided to lock-down the ability to bypass that warning, I've decided on a much simpler solution- Use literally any other browser. Check out this solution-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23047482/3692082