# How to create a custom WPF command to launch my firefox browser?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create two custom WPF commands: one called WebBrowser to launch my Firefox browser when invoked and the other just as a simple exit command when invoked.  I have been messing around trying to figure it out, but I guess I am not as smart as I thought.  I could only figure out the exit command.  How to invoke my browser is making me crazy because I can't figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is what I have so far.

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Commands.CustomCommandSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfTutorialSamples.Commands"
    Title="CustomCommandSample" Height="150" Width="200">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="self:CustomCommands.Exit"  CanExecute="ExitCommand_CanExecute" Executed="ExitCommand_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Command="self:CustomCommands.Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Command="self:CustomCommands.Exit">Exit</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfTutorialSamples.Commands
{
    public partial class CustomCommandSample : Window
    {
            public CustomCommandSample()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void ExitCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                    e.CanExecute = true;
            }

            private void ExitCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                    Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
    }

    public static class CustomCommands
    {
            public static readonly RoutedUICommand Exit = new RoutedUICommand
                    (
                            "Exit",
                            "Exit",
                            typeof(CustomCommands),
                            new InputGestureCollection()
                            {
                                    new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)
                            }
                    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open Firefox specifically and you've guaranteed it's present, you can do something like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(WhereFirefoxIs, SomeUrl);
```

The URL could be something like Firefox's `about:blank`, and can also be optional.

In fact, if you'd rather open a URL in the system default browser, which is probably a bit safer, you can `Start(SomeUrl)` and let Windows decide how to handle it.  However, take care that it's a network URL so that you don't, for example, execute a local file.

Comment: Will just using Start(SomeUrl) automatically open up my default browser? Also, would I enter that as a new InputGestureCollection?

Comment: Yes, `Start()` with a URL has the system grab whatever's registered as the default browser, so it's nicely hands-off. Your best bet would probably be to just duplicate what you're doing for "Exit" and drop the code in your `Web_Executed()` handler or whatever you want to call it.